# Scale animation for ImageView is not working

Tags: java, android, animation, scale

I have created a scale animation for an ImageView. I want to scale it only in the x direction. However when I run the app, the view just pops from scaleX = 0 to scaleX = 1 without any animation.

I have tried different methods to animate my ImageView, but the same problem always appears. Here is my code:

Java:

```java
line.animate()
        .scaleXBy(0)
        .scaleX(1)
        .setDuration(750);
```

XML:

```xml
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/line"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/line"/>
```

I have also tried using the following in Java:

```java
Animation scaleLine = new ScaleAnimation(0f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
scaleLine.setFillAfter(true);
scaleLine.setDuration(750);
line.startAnimation(scaleLine);

scaleLine.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        line.setScaleX(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
```

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Set the initial scale first, then fire off the animation. `line.setScaleX(0); line.animate().scaleX(1)..`;

Comment: That didn't work for me

Comment: Looking at my (working) code, it should be `line.setScaleX(0); line.animate().scaleX(1).setDuration(750).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).start();` You could possibly leave out the interpolator part, but this should definitely work. If you experience issues, look at the logcat for any unexpected lines.

Comment: Also make sure you are running Android 4.0 ICS or higher.